# Comparing two numbers that are approximately equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Table A and Table B. I have two attributes L1 and L2 for each table. I am trying output all the rows for both tables where L1 and L2 are equal for both tables. The problem is that L1 an L2 may differ my some small quantity. So when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA l1 join TableB l2 on l1.L1 =l2.L1 and l1.L2 = l2.L2
```

I get an empty set even though there are records that do match. How do I resolve this problem?

Example:

L1 = 118.4363 for Table A but for Table B L1 = 118.445428

Comment: what is "some small quantity"

Comment: Like L1 = 118.4363 for Table A but for Table B L1 = 118.445428

Comment: @cool_cs I have encountered a similar problem and I am trying to implement this solution, but I don't understand well  the syntax in the statements => what are `l1`, `l2` and `L1` and `L2` referring to ?

Answer (score 18):

Instead of checking for equality, check that the difference is below some threshold (e.g., 0.1, as in the example below).

```
SELECT * FROM 
    TableA l1, TableB l2 
WHERE 
    ABS(l1.L1-l2.L1) < 0.1 
    AND
    ABS(l1.L2-l2.L2) < 0.1
```

Comment: What happens if the tolerance varies though

Comment: @cheeken Thanks for your answer. I have encountered a similar problem and I am trying to implement this solution, but I don't understand well (also from the question) the syntax in the statements => what are `l1`, `l2` and  `L1` and `L2` referring to ?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to devise some tolerance, like say a difference of 0.01.  Then compute the absolute value of the two when subtracted and see if it's within your tolerance

```
SET @tolerance_value = 0.01;
SELECT * 
FROM 
  TableA l1 join 
  TableB l2 
     on ABS(l1.L1 - l2.L1) < @tolerance_value and ABS(l1.L2 - l2.L2) < @tolerance_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ask the engine to return the ones which differ in "some small quantity".

You can choose the rows which difference "abs(a - b)" is between two fixed values.

Like rows where **a-b > 5** or **a - b > x** *and* **a - b < x+10**. for example

Answer (score 0):

Try using the round function in Sybase or SQL Server so 118 matches 118.  For other DBMS find a round equivalent.

mike

Answer (score 0):

In order to @cheeken's answer to work, you must put a semicolon at the last query, otherwise it won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    TableA l1, TableB l2 
WHERE 
    ABS(l1.L1-l2.L1) < 0.1 
    AND
    ABS(l1.L2-l2.L2) < 0.1;
```